# Undo OS X terminal window split

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app

I constantly split my terminal windows accidentally by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (it's so close to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>). I have no idea how to undo this. Any ideas?

Comment: See also [How do I disable Cmd-D in Terminal?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254222/60079).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

To undo the split, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (you can also do it from the **View > Close Split Pane** menu option).

If you wish to reassign the keyboard shortcut for **View > Split Pane** (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) to something else to prevent anything from happening when you accidentally press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, you can do it by going to **System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts**, adding the Terminal.app and entering the menu title (**Split Pane**) with a different shortcut.

Terminal keyboard shortcuts (from [dashkards](http://dashkards.com/terminal)):
[image: Terminal keyboard shortcuts]

Also see:
[Apple - Create keyboard shortcuts for applications](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH3957)

Comment: I'm on Sierra and they changed the keyboard settings.  Not sure how to do this